# How to compare text data values that are in a sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

Here I'm comparing text values in a sqlite database with strings(section,branch, etc...).
Is it the correct way of comparing?  I'm getting no such column error in query() statement.

```
public Cursor getAllRows(String year, String section, String branch,
                         String subject, String date) {    

  return db.query(
      DATABASE_TABLE,
      null, 
      KEY_YEAR + "=" + year + 
        " AND "+ KEY_SECTION + "=" + section +
        " AND "+ KEY_BRANCH + "=" + branch + 
        " AND "+ KEY_SUBJECT + "=" + subject + 
        " AND "+ KEY_DATE + "=" + date,
      null, 
      null, 
      null, 
      null
  );
}
```

logcat

```
04-04 10:31:51.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21928):
   Caused by:
     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
       no such column: CSE: ,
       while compiling:
         SELECT * 
         FROM student 
         WHERE year=2 AND branch like CSE 
         AND subject=SE AND date=04-Apr-2012

04-04 10:31:51.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21928): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
04-04 10:31:51.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21928): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
04-04 10:31:51.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21928): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
04-04 10:31:51.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21928): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
04-04 10:31:51.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21928): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
04-04 10:31:51.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21928): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
04-04 10:31:51.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21928): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
04-04 10:31:51.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21928): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1229)
04-04 10:31:51.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21928): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1184)
04-04 10:31:51.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21928): at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1264)
04-04 10:31:51.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21928): at sharath.android.trail.DBAdapter.getAllRows(DBAdapter.java:100)
04-04 10:31:51.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21928): at sharath.android.trail.MytableActivity.onCreate(MytableActivity.java:52)
04-04 10:31:51.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21928): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-04 10:31:51.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21928): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-04 10:31:51.568: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(21928): ... 20 more
```

Actually CSE is one value that belongs to branch column, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

String constants in a query need to be enclosed with single-quote (') characters. You are interpolating the strings without the quotes, so they are interpreted as column references.

Generally it is a bad idea to interpolate string values directly. You should create a statement with bind parameters.

**This will automatically escape and quote the strings:**

```
public Cursor getAllRows(String year, String section, String branch,
    String subject, String date)
{
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
         DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " +
         KEY_YEAR + "=? AND " +
         KEY_SECTION + "=? AND " +
         KEY_BRANCH + "=? AND " +
         KEY_SUBJECT + "=? AND "+
         KEY_DATE + "=?",
         new String[] { year, section, branch, subject, date }
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot... one more doubt i has if i have one integer value how can i bind in selectionArgs

Comment: @kumar - You can convert it to a String with `Integer.toString(value)`.

Answer (score 0):

can you tell me KEY_YEAR,KEY_SECTION,KEY_BRANCH,KEY_SUBJECT,KEY_DATE are strings which represents column names or direct column names if this were strings which represents column names then

Please try this

```
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,null, 
    KEY_YEAR + "='" + year +"' "
    "AND "+ KEY_SECTION + "='" + section +"' "
    "AND "+ KEY_BRANCH + "='" + branch + "' "
    "AND "+ KEY_SUBJECT + "='" + subject +"' "
    "AND "+ KEY_DATE + "='" + date+"'",
    null, 
    null, 
    null, 
    null);
```

or if this is direct column names please try this

```
return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,null, 
         "KEY_YEAR='"+ year +"' AND"
         "KEY_SECTION='"+section +"' AND"
         "KEY_BRANCH='"+branch + "' AND"
         "KEY_SUBJECT='"+subject +"' AND"
         "KEY_DATE='"+date+"'",
         null, 
         null, 
         null, 
         null);
```